# How to Detech a USB Device Programmatically ? (Arduino - Android)

Tags: arduino, usb, intentfilter, usbserial

I want to Detach USB connected Arduino from my Android programmatically. I am messing around with ACTION_USB_DEVICE_DETACHED action in USB Manager, But still I can not resolve it. Any one have used this intent to disconnect USB programmatically ?

Comment: What's wrong with simply pulling the cable out? What do you expect "disconnecting programmatically" to do? Also, you have your Arduino connected to an android device with a USB cable, right?